# Creating slides / rotating faces

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, path

I am trying to create some slides (like Hamsterball game slides) and I want an easy workflow for that, so I can let my mind go wild with them. Currently, I use a path with a circle set as its geometry bevel object, which works really well, with only one small problem. After I finish the slide, I remove its upper part, so my character is visible on the slide, but not all faces are placed as I would expect, I would like all of them to face upwards, so the character does not fall of the slide. Any help?
[image]

Comment: Have you changed the tilt of the control points?

Comment: I tried playing with the tilt, and clearing it, but it does not help.

Comment: Can you please provide a better image of the faces.

Comment: Sure, I updated the image in the post. I selected the faces that I would want to keep for my slide, but I need them all to face upwards.

Comment: So you created a curve, applied a circle as a the bevel, then converted it to a mesh, and then deleted the unnecessary faces. Now you want the remaining faces to somehow point upwards, right?

Comment: Yeah, exactly that.

Comment: I cannot think of a solution to making the faces point upwards now. But since you are making ramps/slides, I would suggest that instead of using the circle as your bevel object, use a straight line (Just straighten the default bezier curve) The straight line as a bevel object will give you a flat slide like thing. You can also tilt this thing according to your needs.

Comment: Well, this might be a better approach, I'll give it a try, thank you!